make: *** No targets. Stop
why when the make command in the code code throws an error make: *** No targets.  Stop.
Code:
    NAME := program
FLAG := -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): *.c
  clang $(FLAG) -o $(NAME) *.c -lm

clean:
  rm -rf $(NAME)

reinstall: clean all


Did you remember to save the Makefile? that's the kind of error message I'd expect if Makefile was created but empty

Agree with above. I will also comment that when I used make (15+ yrs ago), make required a very specific format for targets and rules. "code" under a target had to be indented with tab characters, not spaces. So check your man make to see if there is any discussion about file fmt. ALSO, when you paste code into your question, keep the mouse-selection active (so code is highlighted) and click the {} tool in the Edit menu for correct formatting as code/data/output/exactTxtOfErrMsgs.

A few other gotcha's about make. The filename must be Makefile (not makefile) or you can use make -f myOthername. The Makefile must be in the correct directory, usually in the "root" of the project, or if making a project with multiple make files, each file must be in the correct subdirectory. So you may have saved your file, but you didn't run your make command from the correct directory.

The most likely reason for this error is having an empty Makefile (or makefile).
touch makefile
make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.

Be aware that if you are using Makefile as shown above, it's still possible for there to be an empty makefile that triggers this error. Remove the file you're not using.
Also note that action lines in your Makefile must be indented by tab rather than spaces:
$(NAME): *.c
        clang $(FLAG) -o $(NAME) *.c -lm

You'll get a different error if you forget this.
Worked scenario for completeness:
# Nothing in the current directory
ls
make


  make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.


# Create "Makefile" and list it
printf 'thing:\n\tdate >thing\n' >Makefile
cat Makefile


  thing:
          date >thing


# Run the "Makefile" recipe    
make


  date >thing


# Create a bogus empty "makefile"
touch makefile
make


  make: *** No targets.  Stop.


